# Can I set remote_user in host_vars or group_vars?

Tags: ansible

I'm starting to write my first serious playbook in ansible.

Something I'd like to do is to specify different `remote_user` values per host. I'm able to set `remote_user` in ansible.cfg, through the CLI `-u` option and even in play variables, like so:

```
---
- name: install dependencies
  hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  vars:
    remote_user: username
```

But setting the var at the host or group level (which makes the most sense for my approach) won't work. For instance, having this file as `group_vars/all` gets me an "Authentication failure" fatal error:

```
---
remote_user: username
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing appears to be undocumented. Specifically, you have this:

```
vars:
  remote_user: username
```

when, according to the [documentation](http://docs.ansibleworks.com/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users), it should be like this:

```
remote_user: username
```

The fact that it happened to work when you did it the wrong way is irrelevant. There is some side effect that makes it work in that case, but of course it won't work in another case, and it may behave differently in different Ansible versions.

To log on as a different user in each host, the usual way is to specify `ansible_ssh_user` in the [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html). Whether this is a variable that can be overridden in `host_vars` or `group_vars` I'm not certain. See also [issue 4688](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4688) for information about how `ansible_ssh_user` and `remote_user` may override each other.

Comment: Yes, Behavioral Parameters can be overridden in group/host vars.

Comment: Is remote_user not a variable then? What is it? TBH, documentation is too lax in this regard. I have been reading for hours and never came across the term "Behavioral Parameter". I didn't know about ansible_ssh_user though, thanks for that.

Comment: `remote_user` is the same category as `name`, `become`, `ignore_errors`, `always_run`, `register`, and so on. You could call them task keywords or task parameters, but AFAICS the documentation doesn't have a name for them, and we rarely need one. Now, [behavioral inventory parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters) are a different thing, and I think that, indeed, the term is overkill; I think they are just inventory-related variables.

Comment: Having accepted your answer, I have to disagree on that "we rarely need [a name]". Names are very useful; in this case they would've helped me distinguish these "behavioral inventory parameters" from task parameters, from other variables. Where they can be set and how they're overriden is very important, and seem to differ between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `ansible_ssh_user` in `group_vars/all.yaml`.

`remote_user` [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameter-remote_user).

(Documenting because I just run in to this quirk in 2023 on `ansible [core 2.14.1]`)

Answer (score 0):

In your group or host vars add a new one with a name like `playbook_username`, then in your playbook change remote_user to something like this - `remote_user: "{{ playbook_username }}"`

Normally host variables don't seem to overwrite remote_user, but this workaround works well enough